# How to loop through directories and unzip tar.gz files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of subdirectories that contain `...tar.gz`
files. I am trying to use `os.walk()` to go through the individual files and unzip them using the `tarfile` module.

```
import os
import tarfile

current_wkd = os.getcwd()

output_dir = '.../Tar_unzip/output'

for dirpath, dir, files in os.walk(top=current_wkd):
    #print(files) produces
    #alpha.tar.gz
    #beta.tar.gz
    #...etc
    for file in files:
        tar = tarfile.open(file)   #this line produces an error:'file cannot be opened' 
        tar.extractall(path=output)
        tar.close()
```

I am trying to iterate through the different directories and extract the `..tar.gz` files. I've also tried to use:

```
...
for file in files:
if file.endswith('.gz'):  #find files that end with .gz 
    #some folders contain other files
    #that may result in an error? 
    tar = tarfile.open(file)
    tar.extractall(path=output_dir)
```

I am really interested in whether python can be used to move around directories (iteration) and perform some functions, such as unzipping files, etc.

Any help is much appreciated. I'm new to Python. Thank you.

Comment: From the edit 27 minutes ago, it looks like you're searching for all gzipped files, not just gzipped tarballs (`file.endswith('.gz')` instead of the original `'.tar.gz'`). So, `tarfile.open('spam.gz')` is going to raise an exception because the ungzipped `spam` is not a tarball. You could fix this by using an `except tarfile.ReadError:` to, e.g., log and skip over the non-tar-files, but it would probably easier to search for `.tar.gz` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) docs:

> Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in *dirpath*, do `os.path.join(dirpath, name)`.

And of course you saw exactly that yourself, printing out `alpha.tar.gz`, etc, which obviously aren't absolute pathnames or relative pathnames from the current working directory or anything else you could access, just bare filenames.

Also notice that every example given in the docs does exactly what's recommended. For example:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(root, name))
```

So, in your case:

```
for dirpath, dir, files in os.walk(top=current_wkd):
    for file in files:
        tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
        tar.extractall(path=output)
        tar.close()
```

One more thing:

```
output_dir = '.../Tar_unzip/output'
```

This is almost certainly going to cause an error. For one thing, `output` and `output_dir` are not the same name. For another, `...` doesn't mean anything; you probably wanted `..`?

Comment: Thank you!! I appreciate the explanation. I had os.path.join originally put I see now where I made the mistake!

Comment: Still same error: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1553, in open
    raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully

Comment: @Novice: That's a completely different error. Most likely because you're trying to read `.tar.gz` files as if they were `.tar` files.

Comment: I'm going through the tarfile docs right now to see if I can figure it out. I agree. Thanks!

Comment: @Novice: Is your actual code just using `tarfile.open(…)` with no other arguments? Because if so, unless you're using a really old Python (I think just 2.3-2.4?), it should handle gzip automatically if you don't pass a non-default mode. You may still want to try handling the `gzip` and `tar` separately to see which one is failing. Also, make sure `tar -tvzf /path/to/foo.tar.gz` works from the command line.

Comment: @Novice: Especially since, from the pathname, it looks like you're on a Mac, and the Mac version of the `tar` command will actually magically handle compression even if you get the extension wrong, so you may not realize the files aren't what they claim to be…

Comment: You were right. Tar was failing. Gzip worked flawlessly. I'll update the question. Thank you!!